# Change color of SwitchPreference AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, switchpreference

How can I change the color of a SwitchPreference after migratin to the AndroidX library? After migrating the switches on-color is changed to white, I want them to be blue. I have tried using theme/style/layout but nothing seems to work.

Edit: 
Apply theme on parent activity with colorControlActivated attribute to fix this issue.

Comment: When reading your edit; is your problem fixed now?